# Why is my android studio 4.0 project structure different?

Tags: android, android-studio, project-structure

I have updated my android studio to version 4.0 and the project structure has changed somehow. I am new to android developing so I can't tell the changes but the folders are red.

Why are they red? Is it an error or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Everything is ok. It's "non-project" files and folders. `build` is generated folder. `.gradle` is generated too and contains some files used by Gradle.
2. You can change the project structure view to e.g. Android. In this case, these folders will be hidden.

[image]